# In Flask, open uploaded file from another request

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, wsgi

I am developing a webservice, in which every thing is contacted via http requests

part of it is implemented in python

the problem is as follow:

```
@app.route("/p")
def request_file():
    result = send_http_request()
    if result:
        load_file()            
    return render_template("upload_form.html")

@app.route("/p")
def accept_file():
    f = request.files['pic']
    save_file(f)
    return "ok"
```

This is pseudocode of what i am doing, the function request file contact an external service , which respond by making form post request containing a report file, this post request handled by accept_file which save the file (i make sure to call flush() and os.fsync() to completely write to the disk), then it reurn ok, which result in termination of the http request made in request_file

then request_file tries to load the file saved by accept_file , and it fails, it tells me that there is no file with that name, after the request finish, the file become available to subsequent request

i am quite sure that i am trying to load the file after i saved it, and i am flushing to disk and calling os.fsync() to ensure writing to disk

What is Hapenning? what is wrong? i have no clue

I have to work that way as my application depends on external service which responds only by making multipart form request with the file

How can i access the file?

What is the real problem? does it relate to threading? to flask globals exposed via contexts? or what?

thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Are you running the view "request_file" on Server A, and the "send_http_request" line makes an HTTP request to Server B. Server B then makes an HTTP request back to Server A, which is handled by "accept"file"? Then, accept_file returns a response to Server B, which then returns a response to Server A so Server A can finish. Then, load_file is not able to find the file that accept_file created? If that's the case, it's probably an implementation detail. Is send_http_request synchronous? Is Server B actually working? It's tough to tell from pseudocode.

Comment: Did you try closing the file in 'save_file'? Can you post the code for 'save_file'?